# flask-jwt-extended: decorator @jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader always revoked token

Tags: python, flask, flask-jwt-extended

in my app.py I initialized flask-jwt-extended as follow:

```
# Setup the Flask-JWT-Extended extension
app.config['RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER'] = False # remove default X-Fields field in swagger
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'  # Change this!
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED'] = True
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_TOKEN_CHECKS'] = ['access', 'refresh']
jwt = JWTManager(app)
```

then I create token in login with snippet:

```
            expires = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
            access_token = create_access_token(identity=payload['email'], fresh=True, expires_delta=expires)
            refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=payload['email'])
```

strangely if I add decorator @jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader to a certain endpoint I always received "Token has been revoked" error message.

```
@jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader
@api.route('/')
class UserList(Resource):
    @jwt_required
    @api.doc('list_users')
    @api.marshal_list_with(user)
    def get(self):
        '''Get all users'''
        users = UserApi.query.all()
        return users
```

As far as I know this decorator is to check whether or not the token is blacklisted and I just create a new token from login, what is the best practice to create a new token & check whether the token is blacklisted or not?

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation of `flask-jwt-extended`:

> This decorator sets the callback function that will be called when a
>   protected endpoint is accessed and will check if the JWT has been been
>   revoked. By default, this callback is not used.
>
> HINT: The callback must be a function that takes one argument, which
>   is the decoded JWT (python dictionary), and returns `True` if the
>   token has been blacklisted (or is otherwise considered revoked), or
>   `False` otherwise.

The `token_in_blacklist_loader` decorator use to set the callback function when a protected endpoint is accessed. You should use this decorator on the function that checks your token wether blacklisted or not. The simple example using memory for saving blacklisted tokens:

```
blacklist = set()
@jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader
def check_if_token_in_blacklist(decrypted_token):
    jti = decrypted_token['jti']
    return jti in blacklist
```

For further information check the sample here: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/blacklist_and_token_revoking/

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to add the newly generated access_token (from the refresh_token) to the Blacklist database? All tokens absent from Blacklist db are assumed to be revoked...

Comment: Please turn this into an assertive answer, to avoid that you are instead asking a question. Consider making a conditional answer like "If the problem is ... then the solution is to ...".